# CSS files loads from server(CentOS) as application/JSON

Tags: css, centos6

I was trying to set up a (public) server for a symfony2 project, everything went well
except I receive back my css file as "application/json" so the style isn't applying on the web page

The machine has CentOS 6.4 with Apache,
I've tried to google(stackoverflow) it but I'm getting different results as I'm not sure how to properly search this problem, from what I've got I have tried to add such things as "AddType/AddHandler" but it didn't work, maybe I'm doing something wrong as I'm not familiar with "server related stuff"

I would like at least to know where to search for the problem server itself or the symfony as I'm new to each one of them

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to add such things as "AddType/AddHandler" but it didn't work, maybe I'm doing something wrong as I'm not familiar with "server related stuff"

First thinks: Check the error Logs.

Simplest way to add additional filehandler, create an **.htaccess** and put in what you need:

```
 AddType application/json .css
```

**Edit:**
If that dont work, show the error logs. The module **mod_mime** must be enabled.

Comment: Hi Adrian, 
when I "httpd -M" I see the module loaded, also added "AddType" to the "httpd.conf" ( to affect other future projects ), in error_log - I get nothing related to this (a  bunch o files not found - I have some broken image links ), there is a "project_log" - empty, service httpd restart - done after every change , when I'm looking at the symfony logs I see the file requested as a css ( matched route )
p.s: also added "AddType text/css .css" - not working, and no errors related to this issue in logs

Comment: Hello,
I tried to load any other css file from the server by hard-coding it, it was loaded without problems, I think the problem relies in the symfony2 now :(